# Invoke JS object constructor from C when object constructor defined inside js module

Tags: node.js, duktape

Using Duktape over microchip 32, everything running well.
BTW, when using module loading( which is also working like a charm), i'm facing a kind of pattern question. 
lets me explains:
I define a constructor inside a js module

```
var MyObject = function(a){
this.a = a;
}
...
module.exports = MyObject;
```

now i'm using this module inside anothers program.

```
const toto = require('myobject');
var dummy = new toto('1');
```

Still working.

Question is : HOW do i call the MyObject constructor from C without knowing the name ('**toto**') affected when requiring the module (which is basically user related).

```
duk_push_global_object(ctx); // [global]
duk_bool_t res = duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -1, "toto"); // [global toto]
duk_push_string(ctx, "1"); // [global toto param0]
duk_new(ctx, 3); // [global result]
duk_remove(ctx, -2); // [result]
```

I whish to use '**MyObject**' instead without constraint the developper to declare

```
const MyObject = require('myobject');
```

I know i can declare the object entirely in c to avoid this, but maybe one of you has already a best practice..
It's seem also that duktape do NOT define access to the global scope into module like nodejs does. (I can also add this to duk_module_node.c, but at last solution..)

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different pattern, i decided the most direct solution is to add a 'global' parameter as the module wrapper (similar to nodejs).
here the small code modification in duk_module_node.c

```
#ifdef ADD_GLOBAL_TO_MODULES
    duk_push_string(ctx, "(function(exports,require,module,__filename,__dirname,global){");
#else
    duk_push_string(ctx, "(function(exports,require,module,__filename,__dirname){");
#endif // ADD_GLOBAL_TO_MODULES

    duk_dup(ctx, -2);  /* source */
    duk_push_string(ctx, "})");
    duk_concat(ctx, 3);

    /* [ ... module source func_src ] */

    (void) duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -3, "filename");
    duk_compile(ctx, DUK_COMPILE_EVAL);
    duk_call(ctx, 0);

    /* [ ... module source func ] */

    /* Set name for the wrapper function. */
    duk_push_string(ctx, "name");
    duk_push_string(ctx, "main");
    duk_def_prop(ctx, -3, DUK_DEFPROP_HAVE_VALUE | DUK_DEFPROP_FORCE);

    /* call the function wrapper */
    (void) duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -3, "exports");   /* exports */
    (void) duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -4, "require");   /* require */
    duk_dup(ctx, -5);                                 /* module */
    (void) duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -6, "filename");  /* __filename */
    duk_push_undefined(ctx);                          /* __dirname */
#ifdef ADD_GLOBAL_TO_MODULES
    duk_push_global_object(ctx);                      /* global */
    duk_call(ctx, 6);
#else
    duk_call(ctx, 5);
#endif
```

defining ADD_GLOBAL_TO_MODULES into duk_module_node.h

```
#define ADD_GLOBAL_TO_MODULES
```

you can now use js code in a module in the following way:

```
var _static = function (value, timestamp, quality, index) {
    this.value = value;
    this.timestamp = timestamp || new Date().getTime();
    this.quality = quality || _static.Quality.GOOD;
    this.index = index || _static.INDEX_NONE;
}

_static.Quality = { GOOD: 0, UNCERTAIN: 1, BAD: 2, UNKNOWN: 3 };
_static.INDEX_NONE = -1;

_static.prototype = (function () {
    var _proto = _static.prototype;
    return _proto;
})();

module.exports = _static ;
if(global) global.DatapointSample = global.DatapointSample || _static ;
```

you can now use

```
new DataPointSample()
```

anywhere or call it from c knowing the name.

I know this oblige to maintain both c and js naming BUT in a microcontroller firmware it's highly acceptable.

Regards.